# Advices on first web application

Tags: android, webview

I have a website about sports new and I would love to make it an application on the Android platform. I already managed to make it with a big view loading an "android like" interface. But I would love to add more functionalities and I want to do it properly (get rid of webviews). I would love to get some advices, ideas, links, tutorials, anything really... to guide me to the right direction.

My project is quite simple, display a list of news, fixtures, or the rankings and clicking on a object would lead the user to a detailed page. List of news => Read news, Fixtures => Read game details etc...

I don't know what's the best approach for it. Requesting an XML from Android, or remotely connecting to the database (if possible ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approach to do this,

1. Expose your content from server using either by web services (soap/rest) or over HTTP call by XML/JSON. Put the reasonable level of security based on need. Android client make a call to server to get the information. This is the best approach and now a days almost all data centric apps.
2. If you want go bit economy way to do then, write your custom CSS for Andorid. Put the filter server end for user agent string. In this way, same page will load in with UI compatible to Android devices.

Both approach are nice. Decision is completely depend on type of your service and need.